# control GPIO outputs

Tags: c++, gpio, pins, ueye

I'm trying to use `GPIO` of the camera as a flash output through its pins in c++. My code looks like that:

```
    HIDS m_hCam;    // handle to camera 
.
.
.   
    IO_GPIO_CONFIGURATION gpioConfiguration;
    gpioConfiguration.u32Gpio = IO_GPIO_2;
    gpioConfiguration.u32Configuration = IS_GPIO_FLASH;

    nRet = is_IO(m_hCam, IO_FLASH_MODE_CONSTANT_HIGH, (void*)&gpioConfiguration, sizeof(gpioConfiguration));
```

This is the link to the [documentation](https://www.prolinx.co.jp/supplier/IDS/uEye_Manual_En/index.html?is_iogpio.html):
And I'm using an Ethernet camera.

My program compiles properly but I don't anything in the output! Do you know what is wrong with my code?